# How can I improve Doctrine2's load time?

Tags: php, performance, doctrine-orm, doctrine, composer-php

I've been researching a performance bottleneck on our server and tracked it down to when I create the Doctrine2 entity manager. I've created a simple test page (that includes our vendor/autoload.php file) and load tested that as a baseline. Then I include and use a file that creates the EntityManager (I don't do anything with it, I just instantiate it).

Load testing when creating the EntityManager significantly increases the average page load time (3+ seconds) and also eventually gives timeouts and 500's. I'm guessing the timeouts are from the CPU being overwhelmed by the amount of work. But the 500's offered some interesting information. The log files showed that sockets failed to open because too many files were open. Without creating the entity manager my server only shows ~5k files open for Apache, but with the EntityManager being made the number of files for all Apache processes goes up to ~100k.

Using webgrind locally with the same test (loading with and without the EntityManager) shows that `Composer\Autoload\includeFile` gets called 48 extra times and takes 15 milliseconds more (for each request) when using the EntityManager.

So my question is: **how can I speed up Doctrine2's load time and reduce the number of files that it auto includes?** (or reduce the time it takes to load them)?

Doctrine 1 seems to have offered a way to compile some of the components into one file http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/improving-performance.html. **Is there something similar in Doctrine2?** Googling didn't seem to turn anything up.

I've installed APC and configured Doctrine to use it as a metadata cache. That helped some, but not as much as I was expecting.

I also already used composer to dump an optomized classmap. That helped a nice amount too, but still doesn't make it ideal.